# Xfinity hotspot not connecting to certain websites via extender

Tags: wireless-networking, router, ip, dhcp, wireless-extender

I am a Xfinity customer and receive xfinity hotspot at my location. The signal is weak so I got an extender. I was able to connect the extender to the xfinity hotspot, however it connects to some sites like Gmail, Outlook, Youtube, Facebook, however it cannot connect to a lot of websites like tomshardware.com, whop.com, reddit.com. I tried the wifi without the extender and they load up fine. I also tried connecting my extender to a wifi with WPA2 securtiy and all the sites load up fine that way also. It is just when I connect to the xfinity hotspot some sites don't load. I am not a networking person but from what I read online it has something to do with Ip addresses and DHCP. Please help.

Comment: In other words, you're able to connect to websites that support IPv6 but not to those that are IPv4-only? What type of extender do you have? What IP addresses does your device have when connected to both networks?

Comment: I am not sure if they are  IPv4 or IPv6 sites. How do I find out. The IPv4 address is 172.20.xx.xxx and IPv6 address is 2601.152.xxx.3ei7.e742.7f6e.67xx